# Why am I unable to select xml nodes by attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
  ...more stuff...  
  <Textbox Name="Textbox93">
      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
      <Paragraphs>
        <Paragraph>
          <TextRuns>
            <TextRun>
              <Value rd:TranslationKey="DATE">Date</Value>
              <Style>
                <FontSize>11pt</FontSize>
                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                <Color>#444444</Color>
              </Style>
            </TextRun>
          </TextRuns>
          <Style />
        </Paragraph>
      </Paragraphs>
      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox93</rd:DefaultName>
      <Style>
        <Border>
          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
          <Style>Solid</Style>
        </Border>
        <BackgroundColor>#82bad9</BackgroundColor>
        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
      </Style>
    </Textbox>
```

This is a repeating structure within a larger xml document. I am trying to pull every node like this: `<Value rd:LocId="DATE_VALUE">Date</Value>`. I am trying to retrieve the nodes like so:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

nsmgr.AddNamespace("nm", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rd", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner");

var nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Value[@rd:TranslationKey]", nsmgr);
```

My nodes count is 0 and I'm not sure why. This looks like the examples I'm seeing on the web.

Comment: Gah, I hate working with XML namespaces in .NET. Have you tried `//nm:Value[@rd:TranslationKey]`?

Comment: Son of a...worked like a charm, @Cameron. I knew damned well it was going to be something stupid I overlooked. Write up a quick answer and I'll get you some points. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh no, not XML namespaces again!

When there's a namespace in the XML document, even if it's the default namespace, all node names (and thus queries) need to be prefixed with that namespace.

So your code should work fine provided you prefix `Value` with `nm:`, like so:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//nm:Value[@rd:TranslationKey]", nsmgr);
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Better run and hide before the namespaces get you!

Comment: Haha, no problem :-)